# Linux, как запретить пользователю занимать больше одного порта?

Tags: linux, port

Нужно сделать ограничение, на кол. занимаемых портов, как и сам порт.

Например юзеру test, присвоить порт 2556, и он может запускать программы только на нём.

Спасибо!

Comment: Смотрели в сторону quota, ulimit, rlimit?

Comment: @0andriy , Нет, но немного осмотрев, не очень видно решение проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

> Например юзеру test, присвоить порт 2556, и он может запускать программы только на нём.

Можно, например, сделать средствами `iptables` как-то так:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner user -p tcp --dport 2556 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner user -j REJECT
```

И аналогично для цепочки `INPUT`.

Это не запретит приложениям пользователя открывать другие порты, но пакеты на них будут блокироваться.

Comment: Проблема в том, что думаю более 150правил подобных, не очень скажутся на пропускной способности.

Comment: [прблема YX](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4900/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-yx)?

Comment: @АнастасияСафонова на 150 вряд ли, но по хорошему надо потестить. см https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/04/11/benchmarking-nftables/